# add the value of all other instances and set this instance to that sum

Tags: c++, loops, vector

i want to take any arbitrary instance of some class; for this instance, i want to add up a value in the other instances. i don't want the value of this instance to be a part of the sum. the code that i have written appears to fall short of that goal.

i have a c++ class foo

```
class foo  
{  
private:  

        static int count ;  
        int someVar ;  
        int anotherVar ;  

        void setCount( newCount )  
        {  
            count = newCount ;  
        }  

public:  

       void doSomething(void)  
       {  
           while ( index < count - 1 )  
           {  
               // don't do the calculation  
               // when this instant is the  
               // one having its version of  
               // anotherVar updated  
               if ( foo == this-> ?? )  
               {  
                   continue ;  
               }  

               someVar += anotherVar ;  
               index++ ;  
          }  
      }  

} ;
```

in other words, i have a vector of instances of foo. i would like take any arbitrary one of the instances add another anotherVar from the remaining instances to the value of someVar for this instance.

in the main, i will iterate over all instances of foo to set this anotherVar to all of other instances' someVar of the current interated instance.

Comment: count is the number instances of the class

Answer (score 0):

You can't just magic `foo` references out of the air, you have to provide them to the method.

```
template<typename Iterator>
foo::doSomthing(Iterator iter, Iterator end)
{
    for (; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        if (&*iter == this) { continue; }
        someVar += iter->otherVar;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<foo> foos = { /* some foos*/ };
    foos.front().doSomething(foos.begin(), foos.end());
}
```